# Unresolved references to typealias, inline functions & extension functions when KMM library is published

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KMM library that was working without issues when the app was depending directly on the module.

But, when I publish the library using publishToMavenLocal & and change the dependency to the generated artifact, all the inline functions, extension functions & aliases stopped working because the reference is not found. The rest is working as expected

Checking the generated libraries the code is in there but it is not reachable.

My guess is that this can be a compilation problem on the KMM part but I am a bit lost trying to figure out what is creating it.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to myself, the issue was caused due to this piece of code in build.gradle:

```
  packagingOptions {
    exclude "META-INF/*"
  }
```

Not much more info about the details of it. If anyone have more information about how removing META-INF affects typealias, inline functions and extension functions I will accept their answer.

Comment: 2 years later, you are a life savior @franmontiel. Thank you very much.